# Getting the id of the anchor tag which was clicked with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have pretty much the exact same problem as this:

[Getting the id of the anchor tag which was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488327/getting-the-id-of-the-anchor-tag-which-was-clicked)

Except I am using vanilla JavaScript and if I understand correctly, all of the answers provided for this question are in JQuery, which I don't know anything about.

I am working with an api called spoonacular.

I search some ingredients and I'm returned an array of objects containing recipes.

```
0
: 
{id: 661447, title: 'Square Deviled Eggs', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/661447-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
1
: 
{id: 638035, title: 'Chicken Cordon Bleu', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/638035-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
2
: 
{id: 641896, title: 'Easy Chicken Cordon Bleu', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/641896-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
3
: 
{id: 652359, title: 'Monte Carlo Sandwich', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/652359-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
4
: 
{id: 663641, title: 'Tomato tarte tatin', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/663641-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
```

I take the results and input them into the innerHTML like so (where data is the array of objects):

```
let recipeTitles = function(){
                return data.map(el => `<a onClick="showRecipe()" href="#" class="recipeTitles" id="${el.id}"><h2 >${el.title}</h2></a>`).join('')
            }
            
document.querySelector('#recipeTitle').innerHTML = recipeTitles()
```

I then want to make it so that whenever one of the individual anchor texts is clicked the the id is extracted so that i can run formulas using it.

This is what I wrote so far:

```
function showRecipe() {
    alert(this.id)
}
```

So the recipeTitles function adds onClick="showRecipe()" to the anchor tag, but when I click it returns 'undefined'.

I tried changing it to onClick="showRecipe" but then nothing happens.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value of id in `showRecipe()` function inside anchor tag like below:

```
let recipeTitles = function () {
  return data.map(el => `<a onClick="showRecipe(${el.id})" href="#" class="recipeTitles" id="${el.id}"><h2 >${el.title}</h2></a>`).join('')
}
```

And then in function just pass a parameter `id` like below:

```
function showRecipe(id) {
    alert(id)
}
```

Now this will grab the value which is passed in the `showRecipe()` function as actual argument